# How Do You Solve a differential equation of the form: $y'=yx+x$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How do you solve a differential equation of the form: $y'=yx+x$

In this case you cannot separate the equation indeed: $y'=yx+x \iff \dfrac{dy}{dx}=yx+x$ And I can't separate it? How does one solve that problem.

The equation I am struggling with is $\dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{y}{1-x^2}+x \iff \dfrac{dy}{dx} = y(1-\dfrac{1}{x^2})+x$

I can't seperate it.
I understood how to solve $y'=yx+x$ But I can't solve the equation above.

What do I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's give it a try assuming $y\neq -1$

$$y'=x(1+y)\iff {dy\over 1+y}=xdx$$

And we have separated. The solution in this case is $y(x)=ke^{x^2/ 2}-1$ for $k\neq 0$. One can see that $y=-1$ is also a solution so the general solution is

$$y(x)=ke^{{x^2\over 2}}-1, \, k\in \Bbb{R}$$

Comment: *y* is a function of *x*, what does your assumption say about functions which are equal to -1 at some but not all values of *x*?

Comment: It may lead to restriction to the domain of definition of a solution. but after resolution we can test that our general solution is a solution that is defined... and works over  all $\Bbb{R}$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Considering $$y'=yx+x=x(y+1)$$ define $z=y+1$ which makes $$\frac{dz}{dx}=x z$$ which is separable.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right)y=x$$

We can use a trick call integrating factor.

$$\exp\left(\int \frac{1}{x^2-1} dx\right)=\sqrt{\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|}$$

Note: we can ignore the constant in the previous integration, we are just interested in one such function.

Multiplying the integrating factor to the original equation, we have

$$\sqrt{\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|}\frac{dy}{dx}+\sqrt{\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|}\left(\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right)y=\sqrt{\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|}x$$

Notice that this is just

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(y\sqrt{\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|}\right)=\sqrt{\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|}x$$

Now you can integrate both sides.

$$y\sqrt{\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|}=\int \sqrt{\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|}x dx$$

$$y=\sqrt{\left|\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right|}\int \sqrt{\left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|}x dx$$